# "npm run CMD" not working

Tags: typescript, npm, tslint

I may be being an "npm numpty" but I can not figure out why when I type:

```
tslint --force --format verbose \"src/**/*.ts\"
```

it works fine but when I type:

```
npm run lint
```

where my `package.json` includes:

```
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf lib",
    "lint": "tslint --force --format verbose \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run lint && echo Using TypeScript && tsc --version && tsc --pretty",
    "test": "npm run build && mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register --recursive test/**/*-spec.ts",
    "watch": "npm run build -- --watch",
    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
```

I get the following error:

> module.js:471
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module './test/parse'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (/Volumes/PEGASUS/repos/mine/logger/serverless-event/node_modules/tslint/lib/test.js:10:13)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)

I also looked in the `npm-debug.log` file and amongst other things it stated:

```
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     tslint --force --format verbose "src/**/*.ts"
```

Of course that precise command *does not fail* which is the whole issue I'm having.

---

Of note, I did see this similar sounding issue -- [npm run cmd fails while cmd on command line works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088724/npm-run-cmd-fails-while-cmd-on-command-line-works) -- 
but the discussed solution makes no difference to the error I'm getting.

---

Also of note, I currently have no linting errors, warnings, or anything to which I'd expect it return an error status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion is likely to be because npm scripts add to your PATH, to include ./node_modules/.bin. That means when you use `tslint` in your package.json, you're referencing the locally installed version in `node_modules`, and when you just use `tslint` directly you're using the globally installed version. Seems like only the globally installed version is working.

You can confirm this by explicitly specifying the path on the command line, i.e. running `./node_modules/.bin/tslint --force --format verbose \"src/**/*.ts\"`. That directly uses the node_modules version, and should give you the same failing result you're seeing with your NPM script.

That doesn't solve your underlying problem though. It sounds like your locally installed tslint is failing to find a file it uses, although I don't know why. Unless there's an obvious cause for this, I think the quickest solution is probably to just delete your `node_modules` folder and `npm install` again, to pull down a new working version.

A fresh install of tslint with all its dependencies should be able to successfully load all its dependencies, and you shouldn't see these issues. If it can't then you probably have a bug to file with tslint.

Comment: I've removed "node_modules" and rebuilt everything and indeed running the command using the local install fails, the global install works. They're both on the latest version. Very odd.

Comment: Either way I think your answer is probably the right answer but what I have left feels like a different issue.

Comment: Is your local install the same version of tslint as the global install? That could easily cause different behaviour (although both should still work). Your error suggests that `node_modules/tslint/lib/test.js` exists and tries to load `node_modules/tslint/lib/test/parse.js`, and that doesn't exist. Any idea why that might happen? On a quick local install for me both are there and seemingly happy.

Comment: I've raised it as an issue on github but it's interesting that you _do_ have the `lib/test/parse.js` file. I do not in either local or global installs. I'm using version `4.0.1`. Is that what you're using?

Comment: I'm using 4.0.2. If I install 4.0.1 in a fresh folder though (`mkdir /tmp/test; cd /tmp/test; npm install tslint@4.0.1`) then /tmp/test/node_modules/tslint/lib/test/parse.js exists immediately. There's something very strange going on in your install process... Maybe it's related to your NPM version? Github bug is the right choice there I think though. Good luck!